# I can't understand this error message in ARM

Tags: debugging, assembly, kernel, arm, shellcode

My assembly code is

```
00000000 <_start>:
   0:   e28f6001    add r6, pc, #1
   4:   e12fff16    bx  r6
   8:   1b24        subs    r4, r4, r4
   a:   1c20        adds    r0, r4, #0
   c:   4a01        ldr r2, [pc, #4]    ; (14 <_start+0x14>)
   e:   4790        blx r2
  10:   4a01        ldr r2, [pc, #4]    ; (18 <_start+0x18>)
  12:   4790        blx r2
  14:   80047dbc    .word   0x8003f924  ; prepare_kernel_cred
  18:   80047a0c    .word   0x8003f56c  ; commit_creds
```

When I execute this assembly code, segment fault is occured and error message is

```
1010201d : 4a
1010201e : 90
1010201f : 47
10102020 : 1
10102021 : 4a
10102022 : 90
10102023 : 47
10102024 : 24
10102025 : f9
10102026 : 3
10102027 : 80
10102028 : 6c
10102029 : f5
1010202a : 3
1010202b : 80
Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000000
pgd = 82d44000
[00000000] *pgd=63b28831, *pte=00000000, *ppte=00000000
Internal error: Oops: 17 [#16] SMP ARM
Modules linked in: m(PO)
CPU: 0 PID: 660 Comm: test Tainted: P      D W  O 3.11.4 #13
task: 86834b40 ti: 8686c000 task.ti: 8686c000
PC is at 0x10102024
LR is at commit_creds+0x78/0x210
pc : [<10102024>]    lr : [<8003f5e4>]    psr: 20000033
sp : 8686dfa8  ip : 00000000  fp : 00000000
r10: 00000000  r9 : 8686c000  r8 : 8000e348
r7 : 00000000  r6 : 10102019  r5 : 0000001c  r4 : 00000000
r3 : 00000001  r2 : 00000000  r1 : 00000001  r0 : 00000000
Flags: nzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA Thumb  Segment user
Control: 10c53c7d  Table: 62d4406a  DAC: 00000015
Process test (pid: 660, stack limit = 0x8686c238)
Stack: (0x8686dfa8 to 0x8686e000)
dfa0:                   00000000 0000001c 00000001 00000000 0000001c ffffffff
dfc0: 00000000 0000001c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 76fb0000 00000000
dfe0: 7ec0dd00 7ec0dcf0 00008643 76f3b8f0 20000010 00000001 00000000 00000000
[<8003f5e4>] (commit_creds+0x78/0x210) from [<0000001c>] (0x1c)
Code: 4a01 4790 4a01 4790 (f924) 8003
---[ end trace 1b1bf4ebadf07b63 ]---
Segmentation fault
```

I think `PC is 0x10102024` means that `14:  8003f924 .word  0x80047dbc` because machine code at 0x1010204 is \x24\xf9\x03\80.
However I don't understand `Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000000` means.
PC is 0x10102024 but kernel NULL pointer dereference is happened WHY?

```
00000000 <_start>:
   0: e28f6001  add r6, pc, #1
   4: e12fff16  bx  r6
   8: 1b24        subs  r4, r4, r4
   a: 1c20        adds  r0, r4, #0
   c: 4a0a        ldr r2, [pc, #40] ; (38 <shellcode+0x22>)
   e: 4790        blx r2
  10: 4a0a        ldr r2, [pc, #40] ; (3c <shellcode+0x26>)
  12: 4790        blx r2
  14: e7ff        b.n 16 <shellcode>

00000016 <shellcode>:
  16: 0000        movs  r0, r0
  18: e28f6001  add r6, pc, #1
  1c: e12fff16  bx  r6
  20: 4678        mov r0, pc
  22: 300a        adds  r0, #10
  24: 9001        str r0, [sp, #4]
  26: a901        add r1, sp, #4
  28: 1a92        subs  r2, r2, r2
  2a: 270b        movs  r7, #11
  2c: df01        svc 1
  2e: 2f2f        .short  0x2f2f
  30: 2f6e6962  .word 0x2f6e6962
  34: 00006873  .word 0x00006873
  38: 80047dbc  .word 0x80047dbc
  3c: 80047a0c  .word 0x80047a0c
```

Comment: Why isn't there any kind of return instruction after your last `blx`? How is the CPU supposed to know that your routine ends there?

Comment: As there is no return instruction after last `blx`, PC is at 0x101020204(_start+0x14). However, I don't know why `Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000000`

Answer (score 2):

In situations where you manage to get outside normal program flow and start executing random junk out of memory, it's always useful to have an idea of what the processor thinks is going on - if that last `blx` returns, you end up executing the data. What does that look like? Well, 'disassembling' arbitrary raw binaries is fun:

```
$ echo '24 f9 03 80' | xxd -r -p - hexfile
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-objdump -bbinary -marm -D -Mforce-thumb hexfile

hexfile:     file format binary


Disassembly of section .data:

00000000 <.data>:
   0:   f924 8003   vld4.8  {d8-d11}, [r4], r3
```

Well, how about that. By sheer coincidence, executing that address as a Thumb instruction results in a load using a base register which happens to be null at the time, hence the page fault.

Comment: Yes, that point I understand. However, my question is meaning of this message `Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000000`. Although I try to execute code after last `blx r2` using `b my_section` instruction, segment fault and `Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000000` message is occured.

Comment: Ah, the updated code is why the address isn't 0x22 - the kernel is executing what still turns out to be a load from the address in `r4`. `r4` contains 0.

Comment: According to updated code at my question, that assembly using shellcode section should be work. Right? 
However, same error is occured. `Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000000` and `PC is at 0x10102028` .
0x10102028 is `add r6, pc, #1` at shellcode section. WHY?